# Segfault on IA-64, but not on IA-32

Tags: c, puzzle

I can't access my [original account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211631/whacko-cracko). Moderators are requested to merge the accounts if possible.
Here is my question.
The following C program segfaults of IA-64, but works fine on IA-32.

```
int main()
  {
      int* p;
      p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
      *p = 10;
      return 0;
  }
```

Why does it happen so?

Comment: @wacko__Cracko: IA-64? Really? You're using Itanium? Or did you mean EMT64/AMD64?

Comment: A pretty bad interview question none the less.

Comment: never, ever cast return from `malloc` in C. If this produces an error, you are missing the prototype.

Comment: This question was pulled straight out of http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545365/why-does-this-code-segfault-on-64-bit-architecture-but-work-fine-on-32-bit?rq=1 which has 58 votes, although it is a later question so really *it* should be the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this code segfault on 64-bit architecture but work fine on 32-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545365/why-does-this-code-segfault-on-64-bit-architecture-but-work-fine-on-32-bit)

Answer (score 8):

In C the default return type is `int` if the function is not prototyped. In ia64 the size of a pointer is larger than an int and so it can segfault.

**Update**: The question is basically why you should always prototype your functions (or include the appropriate headers for that matter).

Comment: For added confusion you can configure an IA64 to use ILP64 and hence `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Yeah, although I think under most Unix/Linux systems and Windows in 64bit `sizeof(int*)` is 64 bit while `sizeof(int)` is 32 bit. I guess there is more software around relying on the fact that `sizeof(int) == 4` than software which assumes `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons I could think of is that the prototype of `malloc` is missing considering pre 99 compiler.

Implicit int (return type) is deprecated. However if your code segfaults that means the compiler assumes that functions (without any prototype in scope) return integer by default. As a result `malloc` would be treated as returning an integer instead of a pointer.

On 32 bit implementations `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` is 32 bits each. On 64 bit implementations `sizeof(int)` is still the same but `sizeof(void*)` is 64 bits.

Trucation of 64 bits pointer to 32 bits might be causing that problem.

Include `<stdlib.h>` to solve the problem.

Comment: Good catach. Since there's no inclusion of the relevant header file, the `int`/`void*` mismatch is a good bet.

Comment: Only if the system is LLP64 or LP64 and not ILP64.

Answer (score 1):

As it's IA64 (itanic) and not x64 it's probably something basic like `malloc` not guaranteeing alignment, cf. `memalign` and early versions of IA64 don't support unaligned memory access.

Comment: But malloc _does_ guarantee alignment for the basic data types.

Comment: Isn't the alignment supposed to be 4 bytes, though, if you're accessing a 4-byte integer?

Comment: `glibc` returns 8-byte aligned addresses other libraries don't, for example HP/UX on IA64.

Comment: OK HP/UX defaults to 16-byte alignment but you can set it to 1-byte alignment and get the SEGFAULT: http://docstore.mik.ua/manuals/hp-ux/en/B2355-60130/malloc.3C.html