# Char array to char*

Tags: c

I am trying to give a value of char array field of a struct to an an element of another struct array.

```
struct Node {
   char template_id[6];
};
struct Node1
{
   char *template_id;
}
void main()
{ 
   Node1 *temp;
   temp_counter=0;
   temp=malloc(5*sizeof(Node1));
   temp[temp_counter].template_id=cur_node->template_id; //getting seq error here
}
```

Tried the followings:

```
strcpy(temp[temp_counter].template_id,cur_node->template_id);
strncpy(temp[temp_counter].template_id,cur_node->template_id,6);
```

Still seq error.
`cur_node` is initialized in different place and it is ok.
Tried the following:

```
temp[temp_counter].template_id="hello"; // It works though
```

Comment: What's the value for cur_node, and where is it defined.

Comment: You have a comment: `//getting seq error here` We can't see what error you get, but if we did, we might figure out what you did wrong. Don't forget to tell us what you're trying to accomplish, what _actually_ happens, and what **YOU** expect to happen.

Comment: Agreed, you need to show the error you're getting, and provide code to reproduce it. You say that "`cur_node` is initialized in different place and it is ok", but if you knew where the problem was, you wouldn't be asking here, so you should provide it. Voting to close until you provide enough information to answer your question. And `main()` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that `cur_node` variable is not well defined. You should post its definition. 
Note, that when you use `strcpy` or `strncpy` you must ensure that the destination pointer points to a proper memory area which is capable of containing the string. For example, you can  allocate this memory area by calling `malloc`.

However, if the `cur_node` is well defined, your code works in both cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_TEMPLATE 6 
struct Node {
char template_id[SIZE_TEMPLAtE];
};
struct Node1
{
char *template_id;
}; 

void main()
{ struct Node1 *temp;
  struct Node cur_node;
  int temp_counter=0;
  memset(&cur_node, 0, SIZE_TEMPLATE); 
  strncpy(cur_node.template_id, "HI", 2); 
  temp=malloc(5*sizeof( struct Node1));
  temp[temp_counter].template_id=cur_node.template_id;
  puts(temp[temp_counter].template_id);
  temp[temp_counter].template_id= malloc(SIZE_TEMPLATE* sizeof(char));
  strcpy(temp[temp_counter].template_id,cur_node.template_id);
  puts(temp[temp_counter].template_id);
}
```

OutPut :

```
HI
HI
```

Comment: Thank you.cur_node is instance of struct Node. template_id is char array with 6 elements and a field of Node.Actually in my code, Node and Node 1 have many other fields which are all double and I do not have any problem for them. To save some space and not confuse you, I just omitted them.

Comment: have you tried this solution? it should work

Comment: I tried the second version of your solution.And it works brilliant. Thank you, man.I am a new to C, and char*, char[], const char* are giving me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Try type casting the allocated memory to the Node type. And verify if the memory is allocated using a NULL check.

```
temp=(Node1*) malloc(5*sizeof(Node1))
if (temp==NULL) exit (1)
```

Comment: [Don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/249237) cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: Don't listen to Kninnug, he doesn't know what he's talking about. Type casting void pointers is a good practice.

Comment: Type casting is bad practice in C it seems. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7545394/207057) explanation is convincing. But if you wanna your code work with C++ you need type casting.

Comment: Typecasting is a terrible idea. If it doesn't work, forcing it to go wrong with a typecast isn't going to solve anything.