# C char*, char**, char***, printing and freeing trouble

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I'm learning how to use pointers in C (with malloc and free), and I'm having some troubles with this exercise. I just want to make an array of pointers, where I want to save the direction of every word. Then I want to do a free() for a specific word, but this free makes my program to crash.

```
int main
{
    printf("Introduce how many words do you want. \n");
    scanf("%d", &numWords);
    getchar();

    char ***array = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**) * numWords);

    if (array == nullptr)
    {
        exit(1);
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) array[i] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)) ;

    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your word number %d: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &(array[i]));
        getchar();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", &(array[i]));
    }

    free(array[1]);

    printWord(array[2])
}
```

Also, I want to make this function because I want to print every character of the word with a space before. It makes my program crash aswell.

```
void printWord(char **array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*array); i++) printf("%c ", &((*array)[i]));
}
```

Don't know how to focus this. What do you recommend to me? Do you find any problems in my code? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: I think you misunderstood how `scanf` works.

Comment: `main{}` is wrong, it should be at least `int main(void){}`

Comment: Think of a string as `char *`, and an array of strings as `char **`. Now think about where e.g. `char ***` would make sense in this scheme.

Comment: You should start [from here](http://ideone.com/aiMSji). There are some small fixes need, which i let you to fix them.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Telling a beginner `char *` is a _string_ (or an array) is a bad idea. They should learn from the very beginning pointers and arrays are different types (and C does not have a special _string_ type).

Comment: `char *` is a pointer. `char **` is a pointe to a pointer. So what would be `char ***`? (Just let's ignore the fact that being a "three star programmer" in C is not a compliment)

Comment: C doesn't have nullptr keyword. It is C++ keyword.

Comment: @PravasiMeet I didn't know that we're allowed to correct OP's code? By doing that you make comments to be nonsense.

Comment: Rolled back original code. Please do not fix OP's code, that's not what the editing function is for. Fix spelling, wording, and formatting.

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages. `nullptr` is a C++ keyword, it has no special meaning in C. Use a C compiler to compile C code. Use `.c` suffix for your source file names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need `char**` and there are a lot of problems and errors which should be fixed:

- `int main{}` should be at least `int main(void){}` you need `(void)`
- no checking `scanf` for errors
- `nullptr` which is `c++` keyword, should be `NULL`
- most important is that way you `free` what you `malloc`ed.
- `casting` malloc is not always a good Idea, [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545365/why-does-this-code-segfault-on-64-bit-architecture-but-work-fine-on-32-bit)

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    long unsigned int numWords,i;
    char **array;

    printf("Introduce how many words do you want:> ");
    if((scanf("%lu", &numWords)) != 1){
        printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numWords * numWords);

    if (array == NULL)    {
        exit(2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
         array[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
        printf("Enter your word number %lu:> ", i + 1);
        if((scanf("%s", array[i])) != 1){
            printf("Error, Fix it!\n");
            exit(3);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
        printf("%s \n", array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numWords; i++){
         free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Introduce how many words do you want:> 3
Enter your word number 1:> Michi
Enter your word number 2:> aloha
Enter your word number 3:> cool
Michi 
aloha 
cool
```

Comment: I think the line
```array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numWords * numWords);```
should be:
```array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numWords);```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your stars mixed up. This is how it works:

- char*: string
- char**: list< string >
- char***: list< list< string > >

Go over your code again and check that every printf("%s" ...) corresponds to a char* and every printf("%c" ...) corresponds to a char. Also turn on all warnings in your compiler, if it is any good it should warn you when you pass the wrong types to printf().

Hint: Your **array** variable in main should be a char**, not char***.