# How to write exact 1MB array in C?

Tags: c, malloc, mpi

I want to initialize an array of size 1MB. So my goal is finally write that 1MB to a file. 
I am curious every time i use this formula it is giving less than 1mb.

```
int len = (1048576)/sizeof(int);
data = (int *) malloc(len);
```

What is correct way ? 
Thank you

---

Edit - As per the comments I have changed the code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *data;
    int bytes = (1024*1024);
    data = (int *) malloc(bytes);
    for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
     data[i] = (int)rand();
     printf("%d",data[i]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

After compiling it and I tried dumping the data like below

```
 mpicc -o a mpiFileSize.c

 ./a > dump.dat
```

Now I see the file size of dump.dat. Why its 2.5MB ?
[image: File Size in Mac]

Comment: `malloc()` takes the number of bytes to allocate. There is no need to divide by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: If your goal is to write one MB to a file; why do you think you need 1 MB in memory too? You could write 1024 x 1024 bytes to your file for example (so a simply loop would do)?!

Comment: programming 101: read the manual before writing code. 102: read the manual before asking a question on SO.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Maybe.

Comment: What is `size(int)` supposed to do? Do you mean `sizeof(int)`? If so, that means you're trying to store 1024^3 / 4 bytes, since each integer is typically 4 bytes.

Comment: oops its sizeof(int)

Comment: Oh, and don't cast the result of an allocation.

Comment: Why dynamic allocation? `int data[1024*1024/sizeof(int)]`

Comment: @mouviciel That's not dynamic. The compiler will turn that into `int data[4194304];` (on a machine with 4-byte ints) I do declarations like that all the time because it makes your logic for choosing the size much clearer than a magic number like 4194304.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I know that's not dynamic: it's my point. Why does OP choose malloc() over a static declaration?

Comment: you get a file larger than 1mb because possibly because of the `include` statements, which literally include (copy and paste) the header files to the file you `include` them in

Comment: @mouviciel Oops, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *data;
int bytes = (1024*1024);
data = (char *) malloc(bytes);
for(int i=0;i<bytes;i++){
 data[i] = (char) rand();
 printf("%c",data[i]);
}
return 0;

}
```

You shoul use character instead of integer.

Comment: Yes It generates 1 MB data.

Comment: why not integers ? any thoughts on that

Comment: Actually character is of 1 byte and integer is 16 or 32 depending upon the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Although it was already properly answered.
Just a plus to the answer, if one wants to choose the amount of MBs to allocate would make something like:

```
#include <malloc.h>

#define Mebabyte (1024 * 1024)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* data = malloc(2 * Megabyte);
    
    // Do your work here...
    
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

If you wanted to allocate more than 2 MBs just change the 2.
As already stated before do not use integers as it's going to have more than 1 byte of size. Instead use char or unsigned char. And as stated by another post, there's no need to cast the result of malloc since void* can be turned to a pointer to any type (and in fact it's done implicitly by the compiler).

see: [Why does this code segfault on 64-bit architecture but work fine on 32-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545365/why-does-this-code-segfault-on-64-bit-architecture-but-work-fine-on-32-bit)